# How to achieve "Built In" bookshelves on this wall?

Tags: carpentry, built-ins

I'm planning to add built-in bookcases to a wall in my space, but I'm facing a few challenges. The wall has baseboard heating running most of its length but not entirely, and there's a breaker panel on one side that can't be moved. The bookshelves I have in mind are typically 11" deep. Additionally, I'd like to incorporate a wall-mounted TV in the middle.

I'm looking for advice on the feasibility of building bookcases above the baseboard heater, and if it's doable, I'd appreciate any design suggestions or input on how to make it work.

I've included a draft illustration for reference, where the red section represents the general idea I'd like to achieve. I'm considering using basic [IKEA bookcases](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/billy-bookcase-white-00263850/) for this DIY project.

[image: nothing]

[image: mockup]

Comment: That electrical box may be a real show-stopper. If it is a simple junction box then it needs to be *accessible* (which could be simply that the shelves next to it can be removed without tools). But if it is actually a **breaker panel** then it needs a 30" x 36" open space in front of it and this plan falls totally apart. If you are not sure, open the front door and take a picture and upload it and we'll know very quickly what you are dealing with.

Comment: It's a breaker panel, I used the wrong term - I guess that sort of answers this whole question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the electric panel on the left side is a *big* problem. In the US, breaker panels require a 30" wide (in this case, along the left wall) x 36" deep (in this case, from the left wall into the middle of the room) space that is to be kept clear of pretty much everything. That isn't always so practical, but putting anything in that space attached to a wall like shelving is absolutely a non-starter.

For details, see [NEC 110.26](https://up.codes/s/spaces-about-electrical-equipment):

> (B) Clear Spaces
> Working space required by this section shall not be used for storage.

Comment: Would it not be at all acceptable to somehow build around the panel, leaving it accessible?

Comment: The *definition* of accessible in this case is that the space is supposed to be empty. I'll try to find a reference...

Comment: I thought the reason behind the 30"x36" open space requirement was so that a person could stand in front of and access the breaker panel?

Comment: @SteveSh Correct. And I think the idea is also that it needs to be fully instantly accessible in an emergency - boxes of stuff, removable shelves, etc. get in the way of that.

Comment: Understood - thank you

Comment: When I was getting my heavy-up, I actually marked the area on the floor with blue tape - some of it is still there. The old panel definitely did not have the required space, but it was presumably grandfathered. The new panel did, but my electrician didn't like the tape because he didn't want to draw attention to the issue (but he was 100% aware of it). But the bottom line is that I figured out how to make it work.

Comment: Thinking out of the box here, though, is there a reason the panel couldn't simply be moved to the left?  It may require a large junction box, but that could be covered by a removable shelf to meet code requirements, no?  Or, if that's an interior wall, perhaps the panel could simply be flipped to open to the wall behind?

Comment: Move? Yes but a non trivial task. Removable shelf? Ok for junction box but not for breaker panel.